# Codeigniter Message: Undefined propertystdClass::$My First Blog

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just started to learn CodeIgnighter and I face lot many problems.

I made one Controller and one view which is given below.

This is My Controller

```
<?php
 class Blog extends CI_Controller{

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

function index(){

    $data['title'] = "My First Blog";
    $data['heading'] = "My Blog Heading";
    $data['query'] = $this->db->get('entries');

    $this->load->view('blog_view' ,$data);
}
}

?>
```

This is my View.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?=$title?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><?=$heading?></h1>
    <?php foreach ($query->result() as $row): ?>

        <h3><?=$row->$title?></h3>
        <p><?=$row->$body?></p>

     <hr>
    <?php endforeach;?> 

</body>
</html>
```

When I execute this so I get this error.

```
PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$My First Blog
Filename: views/blog_view.php
Line Number: 9
```

Now I don't know what is wrong in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the "$" from the foreach variables:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title><?=$title?></title>
</head> 
<body>  
<h1><?=$heading?></h1> 
   <?php foreach ($query->result() as $row): ?>
        <h3><?=$row->title?></h3>
        <p><?=$row->body?></p>
        <hr>
  <?php endforeach;?>
 </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: ya that's work for me. Now please can you say that why that $sign is not work for this variable. Is it call as an object?

Comment: It's because `$body` is a variable and `body` is basicly a string.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, in your view's `foreach` you should do this:

```
<h3><?=$row->title?></h3>
<p><?=$row->body?></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

as others have suggested you should change `$row->$title` to  `$row->title` 
it's pretty simply

`$title` is a variable which contains `My` so when you say `$row->$title` you are actually saying `$row->My` which is going to cuz the error